# Batching to Event Hubs from an ASP .NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, concurrency, azure-eventhub

I have an array of websites that (asynchronously) send event analytics into an ASP.NET website, which then should send the events into an Azure EventHubs instance.

The challenge I'm facing is that with requests exceeding 50,000  per second I've noticed that my response times to serve these requests are into the multi-second range, effecting total load times for the initial sending website. I have scaled up all parts however I recognize that sending an event per request is not very efficient due to the overhead of opening an AMQP connection to Event Hubs and sending off the payload.

As a solution I've been trying to batch the Event Data that gets sent to my EventHubs instance however I've been running into some problems with synchronizing.
With each request, I add the Event Data into a static `EventDataBatch` created via `EventHubClient.CreateBatch()` with `eventHubData.TryAdd()`  then I check to see that the quantity of events is within a predefined threshold and if so, I send the events asynchronously via `EventHubClient.SendAsync()`. The challenge this has created is that since this is a ASP .NET application, there could be many threads attempting to serve requests at any given instance - any of which could be trying to to `eventHubData.TryAdd()` or `EventHubClient.SendAsync()` at the same point in time.As a  poor attempt to resolve this I have attempted to call `lock(batch)` prior to `eventHubData.TryAdd()` however this does not resolve the issue since I cannot also lock the asynchronous method `EventHubClient.SendAsync()`.

What is the best way to implement this solution so that each request does not require it's own request to Event hubs and can take advantage of batching while also preserving the integrity of the batch itself and not running into any deadlock issues?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code for the application insights SDK to see how they have solved this problem - you can reuse the key parts of this to achieve the same thing with event hubs AMQP.

The pattern is ,

1) Buffer data. Define a buffer that you will share among threads with a maximum size. Multiple threads write data into the buffer

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Channel/TelemetryBuffer.cs

2) Prepare a transmission. You can transmit the items in the buffer either when the buffer is full, when some interval elapses, or whichever happens first. Take all the items from the buffer to send

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Channel/InMemoryTransmitter.cs

3) Do the transmission. Send all items as multiple data points in a single Event Hub message,

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Channel/Transmission.cs

They are the 3 classes that combine to achieve this using HTTP to post to the Application Insights collection endpoint - you can see how the sample pattern can be applied to collect, amalgamate and transmit to Event Hubs.

You'll need to control the maximum message size, which is 256KB per Event Hub message, which you could do by setting the telemetry buffer size - that's up to your client logic to manage that.

Comment: This is a good starting point but far more complex than my needs. Are there any other proven solutions that I could base my implementation off of?

Comment: I'd say at 50,000 RPS, you're in the range where you need to consider a solution along these lines. The buffer allows you a synchronised 'collection point' and the transmitter ensures only one thing is doing a send at any one time, 2 of the problems you're facing. If you want to try something else, i.e. locking on the async SendAsync, have a look at SemaphoreSlim https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/. However, the pattern in the answer is actually not far off what you're currently doing and wouldn't be too much effort.